# Floating DIVs in fixed width container to continue align horizontal?

Tags: css, html, width, alignment, containers

I have a fixed width 960px container and I am adjusting my design to fit various screen resolutions. Within the container, I have a few floating `DIV`s using width % and min-width like:

```
width:80%;
min-width:200px;
```

The issue here is that the `DIV`s do not line up horizontally; they end up underneath each other. Previously, I had my `DIV`s on a set width (which I changed to min-width now).

An example of how I have formed DIVs currently:

Container:

```
width: 830px;
float: left;
```

1st-colum:

```
width:100%;
min-width: 200px;
float: left;
```

2nd-colum:

```
width:100%;
min-width: 200px;
float: left;
```

3rd-colum:

```
width:100%;
min-width: 200px;
float: left;
```

etc.

In this example, the 1st-colum DIV covers the entire width of the container and pushes the other DIVs down.

Example of HTML below:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="1stcolum">Hello world</div>
   <div id="2ndcolum">Hello world</div>
   <div id="3rdcolum">Hello world</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, nothing fancy in the HTML either.

Comment: I still have no clue what the problem is, I think it would be in your best interest to create a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/, and clearly describe your desired output and the problem. For example, why `width:100%` with `min-width:200px` if the container is 830px?

Comment: Here's a demo with your code (ids adjusted to be proper and not start with numbers): http://jsfiddle.net/DS28L/ What's wrong with this demo? It's been 20 minutes since your last edit, I've been very patient with you since you seemed to be a victim of abuse/harassment, but I'm giving up now.

Comment: You've made three divs, all of which are 100% the width of the container. **By definition**, they take up the entire width. You've got exactly what you asked for. Why don't you try making them 1/3rd the width, if you actually want them to take up 1/3rd the of the container?

Comment: @WesleyMurch I will review the answer now and get back to you. Cheers.

Comment: Question resolved! ;) Cheers Wesley for your engagement. I mean it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your posted CSS and HTML..

You can't have 3, left floating, divs all taking up the same 100% width unless they stack. This is why the divs stack. Column one takes up 100% of the width, there's no room for column two to also take up 100% of the width unless column two falls below column one.

If you want the columns to actually be columns, you need them to have a width of 33.3%. (one-third of 100%)

And, if you want the columns to be a minimum of 200 pixels wide you don't need a min-width for each column, you simply need a min-width of 600px for the container div.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/qxHqL/1/)

Comment: With Firebug, I was able to determine the percentage and eventually add a min-width for adjustments. Cheers brother!